# A old manga I am trying to remember

Tags: story-identification, manga

It was a manga book, about teens or other people who gain magical power out of nowhere and these people are outcast and viewed as bad. So there was this teenager girl who has the ability to pass through physical things. She learns this power, I think, going through the floor. So she was sent to this school where teenagers had super powers too but the only thing is that she is the only female. So everyone starts being on her case because she was the only female at the school. I can't remember much more, I would be very pleased if someone could find it.

It was black and white, I found the book in a public library, I only read the first chapter then it was going to release other one about a other new girl coming to school. They look American, dressed feminine can't remember what they usually wore. The guy wanting to date this girl. There was a scene where they went out of school so chill out of school. Then there was this guy who was talking about killing or send them away and having a petition. This angered one of the super powered guy and tried to kill him, can't remember what happened after. There was also another scene where to help her with her power they made her go thru and ice block and try her best to stay in there for as long as she can. But at the end of the volume 1, she left cause it was like a school break or winter break.

Comment: Black and white? Color? Viewed on a website? When did you read it? How many chapters do you think it had? Was it still updating? Did any of the characters seem to be of a particular ethnicity? Hair color? Clothing style? Any particularly notable sex or violence (it's one of those things that often stands out in manga, which can anything from safe to ecchi to downright porn)?

Comment: I recommend visiting our [story-identification guidance](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), the [manga/anime specialty one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1), and the [tour].

Comment: If the suggested answer is incorrect, could you clarify a few other details? About what year did you read this? What do you mean by "look American" - just Caucasian, or that the story appears to be set in America instead of Japan? You mention the end of volume one, but also that you only read the first chapter; should that be first volume? "So everyone start being on her" - is this just a regular case of guys wanting to be with/date the only girl?

Answer (score 3):

Potentially [Tokyo ESP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_ESP)? The main character, Rinka Urushiba, does indeed first become aware of her intangibility powers after falling through the floor. Many people in Tokyo suddenly gain a variety of powers (named "ESP") after touching mysterious glowing fish that swim through the air. Later in the series, a school for students with ESP is set up. Doesn't quite match as you said you only read the first chapter, which is before the school was set up.

Comment: Yeah, she gain her powers out of nowhere and story mostly takes place in school.